# lightning:inputField type Date showing both Date Picker and history of dates, how to avoid showing history but show only the Date Picker?

Tags: lightning, date, component, caching

I am using `lightning:inputField` with type as Date, the issue is this field shows two pick-windows *1. Date Picker* and *2. Date-History picker*.
[image]

Please help anyone, if you know if there is any fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

The history is not part of lightning:inputField with type as Date. The history is coming from Auto fill from data, cache, cookies and other site data. You need to delete them from your browser history and that will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replay Kumar, however, even after clearing all browsing history and cookies still the issue remain the same. Not sure of the issue.